# _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value) _onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

**I have this main.dart code:**

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isUserLoggedin = false;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _checkLoginStatus(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            isUserLoggedin = snapshot.data as bool;

            return MaterialApp(
              supportedLocales: L10n.all,
              locale: _locale,
              localizationsDelegates: const [
                AppLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              initialRoute: isUserLoggedin ? '/home' : '/login',
              routes: {
                '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
                '/login': (context) => Login(),
              },
            );
          } else {
            return MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                body: Center(child: Text('loading')),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

**and i am facing this error:**

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)

**in this code in app.dart:**

```dart
PlatformRouteInformationProvider? _defaultRouteInformationProvider;
  BackButtonDispatcher get _effectiveBackButtonDispatcher =>
      widget.backButtonDispatcher ?? _defaultBackButtonDispatcher!;
  RootBackButtonDispatcher? _defaultBackButtonDispatcher;

  // NAVIGATOR

  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? _navigator;

  Route<dynamic>? _onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final String? name = settings.name;
    final WidgetBuilder? pageContentBuilder =
        name == Navigator.defaultRouteName && widget.home != null
            ? (BuildContext context) => widget.home! //error is here
            : widget.routes![name];

    if (pageContentBuilder != null) {
      assert(
        widget.pageRouteBuilder != null,
        'The default onGenerateRoute handler for WidgetsApp must have a '
        'pageRouteBuilder set if the home or routes properties are set.',
      );
      final Route<dynamic> route = widget.pageRouteBuilder!<dynamic>(
        settings,
        pageContentBuilder,
      );
      return route;
```

While running my code in debugging mode, I encountered a situation where it gets stuck in a particular section. The error originates from a file named app.dart, which was not authored by me. My main.dart file contains my code, and I am unsure which specific code in app.dart is causing the error.

Comment: Please write your question with proper code formatting and more information about what you are trying to achieve with the code and what steps you are following.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not clear, but I assume here

```
final WidgetBuilder? pageContentBuilder = 
name == Navigator.defaultRouteName && widget.home != null ? 
(BuildContext context) => widget.home!  ...
```

you are waiting for checking condition:

```
widget.home != null
```

but instead you just assign bool value to the variable `name`:

```
name == Navigator.defaultRouteName && widget.home != null
```

that is false because of `widget.home == null`.

and then here `widget.home!` you geting error.

Comment: you are right maybe my code is not clear i tried to edit the code maybe its better now!

Comment: then provide what exactly is widget.home also